# InputStream Issue - Android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to figure out why my inputstream isn't working correctly. I am trying to connect to a server and get a JSON string and save it into the variable inputJSON, however inputJOSN is empty because my inputstream isn't working correctly. This line of code:

```
inputJSON = ConvertByteArrayToString(getBytesFromInputStream(inputStr));
```

doesn't seem to be working properly and I'm not sure why?  I do think there is an issue with my length variable in my getBytesFromInputStream() method.  If there is I'm not sure if that is it or how to fix it.

Here is my code for the getBytesFromInputStream() method:

```
public static byte[] getBytesFromInputStream(InputStream is)
        throws IOException {

        // Get the size of the file
        long length = is.available();
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "INPUTSTREAM LENGTH:"+length); 
        if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        // File is too large
        }

        // Create the byte array to hold the data
        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) length];

        // Read in the bytes
        int offset = 0;
        int numRead = 0;
        while (offset < bytes.length
        && (numRead = is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length - offset)) >= 0) {
        offset += numRead;
        }

        // Ensure all the bytes have been read in
        if (offset < bytes.length) {
        throw new IOException("Could not completely stream ");
        }

        // Close the input stream and return bytes
        is.close();
        return bytes;
}
```

Here is the thread I'm using to set inputJSON, this thread gets started in onCreate():

```
     public RepeatingThread() {
     }

     @Override
     public void run() { 
          try {
              //outputstrwr.write(outputJSONserv);  //UNCOMMENT IF NEED TO SEND DATA TO GET JSON BACK
              inputJSON = ConvertByteArrayToString(getBytesFromInputStream(inputStr));
          } catch (IOException e) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e.printStackTrace();
          }

          Log.e(LOG_TAG, "IN REPEATINGTHREAD-INPUTJSON:" + inputJSON);
          refreshViewModels(inputJSON);
          mHandler.postDelayed(this, 3000);       
     }
}
```

Here is the code for ConvertByteArrayToString():

```
public String ConvertByteArrayToString(byte[] b) { 
    // byte[] to string
    String input = new String(b);
    return input;
}
```

Here is the code I have for onCreate() :

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Before OnCreate() Try");
    try {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "In OnCreate() Try");
        socket = new Socket("23.23.175.213", 9000);  //Port 1337
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Created Socket");
        dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Created DataOutputStream");
        dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Created DataInputStream");

        //out = new OutputStream();
        out = socket.getOutputStream();
        inputStr = socket.getInputStream();

        p = new Profile();
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Created Profile Instance");

        //Gets the local profile via JSON and converts into Profile type
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Created Gson Instance" + "GetProfileJSONStr:" + p.getProfileJSONStr());
        p = gson.fromJson(p.getProfileJSONStr(), Profile.class);
        setProfile(p);
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Converted Profile to JSON");

        //Gson gson = new Gson();
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Before: outputJSON = gson.toJson(p);");
        outputJSON = gson.toJson(p).toString();
        outputJSON = removeExcessStr(outputJSON);
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "ProfilePicStr Base64:"+p.getProfilePicStr());

        outputJSON = outputJSON.replace("Name","name");
        outputJSON = outputJSON.replace("TagLine","message");
        outputJSON = outputJSON.replace("Title","title");
        outputJSON = outputJSON.replace("Company", "company");
        outputJSON = outputJSON.replace("Industry","industry");
        outputJSON = outputJSON.replace("WhatIDo","whatido");
        outputJSON = outputJSON.replace("WhoDoIWantToMeet","meetwho");
        outputJSON = outputJSON.replace("WHOOZNEAR_PROFILEPIC","photo");
        outputJSON = outputJSON.replaceAll("[c][o][n][t][e][n][t][:][/][/][a-zA-Z0-9]+[/][a-zA-Z0-9]+[/][a-zA-Z0-9]+[/][a-zA-Z0-9]+[/][a-zA-Z0-9]+", getPicBase64Str()); /*"helloworld2"*/

        if (!outputJSON.contains(",\"photo\":")) { 
            outputJSON = outputJSON.replace("}",",\"photo\":"+"\"IconnexUs\"}");
            outputJSON = outputJSON.replace("}",",\"photo\":"+"\""+getPicBase64Str()+"\"}");
            outputJSON = outputJSON.replace("}",",\"status\":\"enabled\"}");
        }
        else { 
            outputJSON = outputJSON.replace("}",",\"status\":\"enabled\"");
        }

        outputJSONserv = "{\"to\":\"broadcast\",\"type\":\"1\",\"payload\":"+outputJSON+"}";

        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Created outputJSON:" + outputJSON);
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Created outputJSON Server:" + outputJSONserv);
        JSONObject outObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            outObject.put("photo", "hello");
            outObject.put("type", "50");
            outObject.put("payload", outputJSON);
            outputJSON = gson.toJson(outObject).toString();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Value of PROFILEPIC STRING FROM PROFILEMAP: "+profileMap.get("WHOOZNEAR_PROFILEPIC"));
        p.setProfilePicStr(ConvertandSetImagetoBase64(profileMap.get("WHOOZNEAR_PROFILEPIC")));
        //String headerJSON = gson.toJson(outObject).toString();
        outputJSON = outputJSON.substring(nthOccurrence(outputJSON, '{', 2)-1, nthOccurrence(outputJSON, '}', 1)-1);

        outputstrwr = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()), true);
        outputstrwr.write(outputJSONserv);

        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Base64 String:"+p.getProfilePicStr());
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Sent dataOutputStream");
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Before initEventHandlers");
    initEventHandlers();
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "After initEventHandlers");
    //refreshViewModels();

    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Start Repeat Thread");
    rt = new Thread(new RepeatingThread());
    rt.start();
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Started Repeat Thread");
}
```

Code for refreshViewModels():

```
    public void refreshViewModels(String inputJSON) {

        try {
            ListView servicesListView = (ListView) this
                    .findViewById(R.id.profilesListView);

            String[] from = new String[] { "profilePic", "neighborName",
                    "tagLine" };
            int[] to = new int[] { R.id.avatar, R.id.username, R.id.email };

            // prepare the list of all records
            List<HashMap<String, Object>> fillMaps = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
            List<Profile> profiles = new ArrayList<Profile>();

            // Clear the position mapping list and reset it
            this.posMap.clear();
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "NEW inputJSON: " + inputJSON);
            inputJSON = getPayloadStr(inputJSON);
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "NEW inputJSON2: " + inputJSON);
            JSONArray profileArray = new JSONArray(inputJSON);

            for (int i=0; i<profileArray.length(); i++) { 
                JSONObject jsonObject = profileArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Gson gson = new Gson(); 
                Profile p = gson.fromJson(gson.toJson(jsonObject).toString(), Profile.class);
                profiles.add(p);
            }

            int pos = 0;

            // Creates the fillMaps list for the listAdapter
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Profiles size: " + profiles.size());
            //showToast("Profiles size: " + profiles.size());
            for (Profile p : profiles) {
                // Create mapping for list adapter
                HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                map.put("profilePic",
                        p.getAttributeValue("photo")== null? "Not Set" : p
                                .getAttributeValue("photo"));
                map.put("neighborName",
                        p.getAttributeValue("Name") == null? "Not Set" : p
                                .getAttributeValue("Name"));
                map.put("tagLine",
                        p.getAttributeValue("TagLine") == null? "Not Set" : p
                                .getAttributeValue("TagLine"));
                fillMaps.add(map);

                // Reset the postion mapping
                this.posMap.put(pos++, p);

            }

            ListAdapter servicesListAdapter = new myAdapter(this, fillMaps,
                    R.layout.listitem, from, to);
            servicesListView.setAdapter(servicesListAdapter);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error making list adapter: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

Code for getPayloadStr():

```
    public String getPayloadStr(String profileString) {
        Log.e("LOG_TAG", "Profile Str:"+profileString);
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*?payload\":(.*)\\}");

        Log.e("LOG_TAG", "I got here 1");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(profileString);
        Log.e("LOG_TAG", "I got here 12");
        //Matcher m = responseCodePattern.matcher(firstHeader);
        matcher.matches();
        matcher.groupCount();
        //matcher.group(0);
        Log.e("LOG_TAG", "I got here 2"+matcher.group(1));
        return matcher.group(1);
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this (inputstream)  *network* stream? What is *output* of `is.available()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you should have to verify the *InputStream* (whether is has data or not - do not rely on `available()` method.)  and you are reading *whole*  stream at once so no need to *use* `while` loop.

I suggest you to use `BufferedReader`,

```
public static String getStringFromInputStream(InputStream is)
        throws IOException {
   StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
   BufferedReader reader=null;
   String line=null;
   try{
      reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
      while( (line=reader.readLine()) !=null){
           sb.append(line);
      }
   }catch(Exception ex){
       //
   }finally{
      if(reader!=null){
          try{
              reader.close();
          }catch(Exception ex) { }
      }
   }
  return sb.toString();
}
```

Or to return byte[],

```
public static byte[] getBytesFromInputStream(InputStream is)

    .....
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    BufferedInputStream bin=new BufferedInputStream(is);

    int numRead=0;
    byte []bytes=new byte[1024];
    while( (numRead=bin.read(bytes))>0)
    {
        bos.write(bytes, 0, numRead);
    }
    bos.flush();
    byte []totalBytes=bos.toByteArray();
    .....
    return totalBytes;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

On multiple Java platforms, I have found InputStream.available() to be unreliable.  If you look at [the Android API docs,](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStream.html#available%28%29)  it says the same.  I would try to avoid that method altogether.